# calling uniq and sort in different orders in shell

Tags: optimization, shell, performance, sorting, uniq

Is there a difference in the order of `uniq` and `sort` when calling them in a shell script? I’m talking here about time- and space-wise.

```
grep 'somePattern' | uniq | sort
```

vs.

```
grep 'somePattern' | sort | uniq
```

a quick test on a 140 k lines textfile showed a slight speed improvement (5.5 s vs 5.0 s) for the first method (get uniq values and then sort)

I don’t know how to measure memory usage though …

The question now is: does the order make a difference? Or is it dependent on the returned lines from grep (many/few duplicates)

Comment: I would humbly recommend accepting a different asnwer - sort -u is the correcter way of doing this than either of your alternatives.

Comment: sure, but the accepted answer explains the _why_ better

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only *correct* order is to call `uniq` after `sort`, since the man page for `uniq` says:

> Discard  all  but one of successive identical lines from INPUT (or standard input), writing to OUTPUT (or standard output).

Therefore it should be

```
grep 'somePattern' | sort | uniq
```

Comment: I've used | uniq | sort | uniq when grepping gigabytes worth of stuff out of sorted files just to try to keep the sort from having to sort an excessive amount of data.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that `sort -u` is suited to this exact scenario, and will both sort and uniquify things.  Obviously, that'll be more efficient than calling `sort` and `uniq` individually in either order.

Comment: `sort -u` is a great hint, and no doubt, it’s more efficient than calling the two in either order. BUT, the order makes a difference (uniq | sort not working)

Comment: In a quick test, I found that `sort -u` is about 7% faster than `sort|uniq`.

Answer (score 3):

uniq depends on the items being sorted to remove duplicates(since it compares the previous and current item), hence why sort is always run before uniq. Try it and see.