# Unexpected difference with sort -u and uniq -u

Tags: linux, sorting, uniq

Case: List all unique filenames in a directory.

```
$ ls 
a.h  a.i  b.h  b.i  c.h  d.i
```

So `c` and `d` are unique in this case. For fixed width we can do:

```
$ ls | uniq -w1 -u
c.h
d.i
```

Not very helpful though as filenames won't be fixed width and `uniq` can only skip fields *(i.e. ignore fields from left to right not right to left).*

```
ls | sort -u -t. -k1,1
a.h
b.h
c.h
d.i
```

I thought `sort -u` was equivalent to `uniq -u` *([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382936/sort-uniq-in-linux-shell))* and with `sort` being able to sort and a given field I expected the output to be `c.h` and  `d.i` but it's not.

Any thoughts?

*Note: I don't need help solving the problem, for instance one solution is just reverse the data twice:*

```
$ ls | rev | uniq -u -s1 | rev
c.h
d.i
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort -u` is equivalent to `sort | uniq`, i.e. no flags for `uniq` given.

Comment: Or in other words: `uniq` only works correctly if the input is already sorted